# Scrolling tab bar items with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

**Precondition**

I have a tab bar on my application, each tab labels include icons and text. 
Users can navigate between tabs by tapping a tab. Once an edge tab has been fired, other tabs should shift left or right.

---

**Expected Result**

I want it to work like **[Web Material Component's Scrolling tabs](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/tabs)**.

### [image]

---

**Problem**

I not sure how to shift the tabs by using pure JavaScript when edge tab has been pressed. Can anyone else give some tips for me?

---

See the code snippet below:

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
  let target = e.srcElement || e.target;
  console.log(target);
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50rem;
  height: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 7rem;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 22%;
}

.sub-menu:active {
  color: gray;
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-title {
  height: 1.7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex-container" onclick="clickHandler(event)">
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-behance fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-codepen fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-eercast fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-fort-awesome fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-flickr fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-skype fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
    <span class="menu-title">Action 10</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try my code:

```
function clickHandler(el) {
   const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
   const winWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth
   const widthScroll = winWidth * 33 / 100
   if (rect.left <= 0 + 10)
   {
        document.getElementById('main-menu').scrollLeft -= widthScroll ;
   }
   if (rect.right >= winWidth - 10)
   {
        document.getElementById('main-menu').scrollLeft += widthScroll ;
   }
 }
```

This is demo link https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/BeagOo

You can add more animation for effect when scroll

Comment: Thanks, but items should be truncated in both (left/right) side.

Comment: Do you see my demo link? Its working both (left/right)

Comment: I’m sorry that I didn’t explain clearly. The Action 2 will also cut in half when Action 5 was triggered.

Comment: So easy. You only change value that scrollLeft to (`widthScroll` variable). Re-Check my edit post

Comment: `if (rect.left <= 0 + 10)`, why `10` here?

Comment: You can change this number. Its my trick for the item is last left or last right